# Fetching Javascript Proxy for ASMX Web Service Fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis-7.5, asmx

I have an ASMX web service at "~/Services/Address.asmx" in my asp.net web application project.  The web service is being called via auto-generated java script proxy like so

```
function ZipCode_change(sender) {
    window.FoodSafety.WebUI.Services.Address.GetZipCodeInfo($("#EditorAddressZip").val(),
            function (result) {
                UpdateCounties(result.Counties, result.CountyKey);
                $("#EditorAddressCity").val(result.City);
                $("#EditorAddressState").val(result.StateKey);
            });
}
```

This call works perfectly when debugging in the development environment, and in my full staging server (compiled as release).  However, when deployed on the production server, the browser receives a `500: Server Error` when trying to load the proxy.js file from "/Services/Address.asmx/js".  This happens well before the the javascript even makes the call; it happens as the page is loading the js file, before the page loading is even complete.

The Chrome developer console displays this error:

> https://SomeWebSiteUrl.com/Services/Address.asmx/js Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

There is an error in the server's event log:

> Exception information:
>       Exception type: InvalidOperationException
>       Exception message: No web service found at: /Services/Address.asmx.
>      at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetWebServiceData(HttpContext
>   context, String virtualPath, Boolean failIfNoData, Boolean
>   pageMethods, Boolean inlineScript)    at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetWebServiceData(HttpContext
>   context, String virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceClientProxyGenerator.GetClientProxyScript(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestClientProxyHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.HandlerWrapper.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Both the staging the the production server's environments are identical as far as I can tell, Windows Server 2008r2, with .net 4.5.

Any help resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Bindings from web.config:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding">
        <security mode="Transport" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
<system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Could you check and let me know your web.config's Security mode type in WebHttpBinding?

Comment: I have no `WebHttpBinding` element in any of the web.config files.  The closest thing I have is a `binding` element named "BasicHttpBinding" inside a `basicHttpBinding` element.  The `mode` attribute of the `security` element inside that is "Transport".  This is the same on all 3 systems. I've added that section of web.config to my answer.